# Centering a Popup Modal with Responsive Height/Scroll

Tags: html, css, popup, popupwindow

Ok, so I'm building a popup for our site. I need it to be centered on the screen, with max width and max-height values set so that it's never 100% of the screen. I also want it to show a scrollbar when applicable for the y-axis.

I suspect that my issue lies with using display: table for the modal, which I am doing so that the modal fits the height of the child elements within it. I'm guessing it has a conflict with the weird combination of max-height, overflow: auto, etc. that I'm trying to use. Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Here is a demo with the SASS/markup. If you resize your browser to be short, you can see how it doesn't set it to scroll but instead just puts the edges of the box outside of the screen.

http://codepen.io/heatherthedev/pen/deauy

Answer (score 0):

Add this property to your .popup CSS . overflow-y: auto;

This should solve the scroll with in that div issue. For resizing, you can invoke the method $(window).resize() when the user scroll the pane or the view.